# Стили таблиц Pandas

Tags: pandas, excel

Получил таблицу, но каждый раз приходится делать выравнивание. Можно как-то настроить, чтоб вся имеющаяся информация в ячейке отражалась сразу?
И как можно сделать ячейки с названиями столбцов другого цвета?

Comment: Таблица pandas - это структура данных в памяти, у нее нет выравнивания ячеек и цветов. Где именно вы делаете выравнивания и цвета ячеек? При выгрузке в excel?

Comment: Да, хотел, чтоб при выгрузке в Excel файл происходило выравнивание

Comment: @insolor Не, ну настраиваемые стили то в пандасе есть, а вот насколько они сохраняются при выгрузке в эксель - я не знаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Конечно же, нет. Это просто фронтовая постобработка. Через `xlwings` можно как делать выгрузку в **Excel** из `DataFrame`, так и настраивать оформление в итоговом файле. Что конкретно Вы хотите?

Comment: Основное - чтоб всю информацию содержащую в ячейке было видно сразу. А также понять, как можно изменить фон ячеек содержащих название столбцов